# MUI: navigate to page and set datasource

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

I'm using WPF ModernUI and I would like to navigate to a page and set the page DataContext as well.

To navigate I'm using the following:

```
NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("view/pages/TaskEditPage.xaml", this);
```

Is there any other way to navigate to a page or is there any way to get the instance of that page so I could set the DataContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time (and the only one) since I used ModernUI , navigation usually was something like the following:

```
NavigationCommands.GoToPage.Execute("view/pages/TaskEditPage.xaml#TaskID=xyz", this);
```

Then you can:

```
public void OnFragmentNavigation(FragmentNavigationEventArgs e)
{
  //e.Fragment will be "TaskID=xyz"
  RetrieveTaskFromStore(e.Fragment)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ModernFrame` control, which hosts the current page, inherits from `ContentControl` and so has a `Content` property, which is the current page.

But, using fragment navigation provides good separation of concerns. Let the view decide which view model class to use as the `DataContext` and use fragment navigation to help load particular data for the view model.